# Using Dominated Convergence Theorem to compute limit?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to compute the following limit using the Dominated Convergence Theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^\pi f_{n}(x) dx$$
where $$f_{n}(x)=(sinx)^{1\over \log_{10}(log_{10}(n))} \text{ for }n>10. $$
So far, however, I haven't been able to find a suitable dominating function, $g(x)$. 
If I'm not mistaken, $|f_{n}(x)|\leq 1$, but $g(x) = 1$ is not integrable since it's a constant function. I would appreciate any hints or tips in the right direction.

Comment: We are integrating over a finite interval, so 1 should be integrable, no?

Comment: Yes, you're right - thank you! I overlooked that for some reason initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for all $x$, $f_n(x)I_{[0,\pi]}(x)\leq I_{[0, \pi]}(x)$ and it is the case that $ I_{[0, \pi]}(x)$ is an integrable function.

Answer (score 1):

$|(\sin{x})^{1\over \log_{10}(\log_{10}(n))}| \leq 1$ since $\sin{x}\geq 0$ on $[0,\pi]$

So by Bounded Convergence Theorem you have tha conclusion.